# Hide Rows in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide rows using VBA. I have the start row from where I have to start hiding the rows. I have written the following code:

```
sht.Rows(32 + end_row).Resize(, 65536 - (32 + end_row)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

where `end_row` is the row til which the data will be populated in my excel sheet and `32` is the index of the row from which data will start populating.
When i am trying to run this code it gives an error,

> application-defined or object-defined error

How do I resolve this and what should be the best way to do it?

Comment: if the sum of `32 + end_row` is greater than the row limit in your version of Excel, the error will occur.  Make the Locals pane visible and step thru your code maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement.

```
Resize(, 65536 - (32 + end_row)).Select
```

you mix up rows and columns..

you probably mean `Resize(65536 - (32 + end_row)).Select`

```
Resize([Rows],[Columns])
```

Much better to write something like this though (avoid use of `Select`)

```
Sheet1.Rows.Resize(65536 - (32 + end_row)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

This code hides all the rows at the top of the sheet though and leaves the rows at the bottom of the sheet visible. I assume that you want this the other way round.

---

This piece of code may help. It will hide all blank rows below the last entry in Column A

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheet1

sht.Range(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1), sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Rows.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way could be :

```
'Expected sht is a sheet object, else use : ActiveSheet.Rows("32:" & end_row).Hidden = True
sht.Rows("32:" & end_row).Hidden = True
```

*Avoid to use the 65535 limitation*